# wrong-type-argument char-or-string-p nil when doing RET in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I have the following error every single time I press `RET` in org-mode :
wrong-type-argument char-or-string-p nil.
It's usually ok but it's bothering when it breaks a tag at the end of a line for example.

Here is the complete stack trace :

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument char-or-string-p nil)
insert-before-markers-and-inherit(nil)
org-comment-line-break-function(t)
default-indent-new-line(t)
do-auto-fill()
self-insert-command(1)
newline()
org-return()
funcall-interactively(org-return)
call-interactively(org-return nil nil)
command-execute(org-return)
```

I'm using a GUI Emacs 25.2.1 (Org mode 8.2.10) on Windows 10

Any idea to fix it ? I've made several searchs on these functions in the doc but without success. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 3):

`org-comment-line-break-function` unconditionally inserts `fill-prefix` at the beginning of a new line.
The default value of `fill-prefix` is nil standing for "no prefix". That is not acceptable for `insert-before-markers-and-inherit`.

Customize the variable `fill-prefix` to the string `""` instead of nil and the error will go away.

The variable `fill-prefix` is buffer-local. If the global initialization of `fill-prefix` with the empty string gives you any trouble you can also set it specifically for org files in `org-mode-hook`. Just copy the following text into your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

```el
(defun org-config-fill-prefix ()
  "Set `fill-prefix' to the empty string."
  (setq fill-prefix ""))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org-config-fill-prefix)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't change the problem unfortunately. It doesn't yield an error anymore but still not working (it breaks the tag at the end of line)

Comment: @loukios org-mode is at [version 9.1.6](https://orgmode.org/) now. Could you update and look whether the problem persists?

Comment: Shouldn't `org-comment-line-break-function` be modified so that if `fill-prefix` is `nil` it does TRT, rather than passing it on to a function that is expecting strings?