# org-roam ignores fill-prefix when set via use-package

Tags: use-package, org-roam

Because of [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38943/12999) I set `fill-prefix` to `""`. When I do this explicitly via `M-:` it works as expected.

I need a solution for `use-package` here.

When I try to make this setting *specific to org-roam buffers* the behaviour is not as expected and `C-h d RET fill-prefix` still tells me that it is `nil`.

I set it in the `:config` section like this.

```el
(use-package org-roam
  :init
  (setq org-roam-v2-ack t)  ; do not show migration warning after startup
  :custom
  (org-roam-directory "~/tab-cloud/my.org-roam")
  :bind (("C-c n l" . org-roam-buffer-toggle)
     ("C-c n f" . org-roam-node-find)
     ("C-c n i" . org-roam-node-insert)
     :map org-mode-map
     ("C-M-i" . completion-at-point)
     )
  :config
  (org-roam-db-autosync-mode)
  (setq fill-prefix "")  ;; see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38943/12999
      )
```

Comment: Try setting it globally in your init file or customizing it. Are you trying to make it buffer-local for `org-roam` buffers only?

Comment: Yes. org-roam buffers only. Makeing it global does not explain why my "solution" doesn't work. What do you mean with "customizing"?

Comment: Using the `Customize` interface: do `C-h v fill-prefix` and click on the `customize` link. But that's also a global change, so it won't work for what you want to do.

Comment: I don't know how to use `use-package`, but you should be able to do it the old fashioned way by adding the setter to the major mode hook: `(add-hook 'org-roam-mode-hook (lambda () (setq fill-prefix "")))`.